# High index fragmentation

Tags: sql-server

we have a SQL Server database running that for some reason encounters massive index fragmentation (up to 85% and higher) and we find ourselves rebuilding indexes almost daily to stop this.

We are at a loss however why this is happening. The tables use newsequentialid() to generate the new GUIDs (primary keys), so we think new rows should always be added at the end, but we feel like this is not the case which maybe results in high fragmentation rate?

Does anyone have any ideas, things we can try to alleviate this problem or further diagnose it?

An example table would be :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmailMessages](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.EmailMessages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmailMessages] ADD  CONSTRAINT  [DF__EmailMessage__Id__7993056A]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [Id]
 GO
```

Comment: How big is this table? do you have any jobs that shrink the database?

Comment: Is the `Name` column updated after the initial insert?

Comment: Use a fill factor less than 100

Comment: No jobs that shrink the database. Row count at this moment: 240 000 records. 

The example table above should not be updated.

Comment: Fill factor seems to be set to zero for all indexes on this table.

Comment: Some time ago I was working on an application with a similar behaviour. The problem was, that new rows where created outside (C#-application) and brought a GUID-Id with them. So the existing default with `newsequentialid()` was of no help. It might help to create the clustered index from a *growing* column and build the index on your GUID-id separately.

Comment: Is the index fragmentation a *problem*? I have a critical table in one of my OLTP databases with an index that has >97% fragmentation according to SSMS (page fullness is a lot better). Apart from disk use, it's irrelevant because it's only ever used for index seeks, where the fragmentation is barely noticeable. Actively and aggressively defragmenting it would make things *worse*. If it is a problem because you also need to scan it a lot, consider making the clustered index on an identity that is never used and only there to keep rows in order.

Comment: Hello Jeroen Mostert: yes, the fragmentation on certain of our tables does definitely cause a problem, because as soon as we rebuild them, a performance problem goes away. 

I was hoping anyone would have an idea of why the indexes get fragmented so easily or that there might be some reason I'm overlooking for this problem, but I guess it's not so clear as I would have liked :-)

Comment: If your table is never modified (no updates, no deletes), then the only possible source of fragmentation is `ID` not being as sequential as you like, per Shnugo's comment. Check what's actually in that column -- sequential GUIDs are easy to spot as they all end in the same byte sequence.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen. We use newsequentialid() to generate them, but as we have just learned, these are only sequential until Windows is restarted. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql). This is most likely our problem.

Comment: I say it's most likely our problem because we recently moved the app to a server where we have full control and the server has definitely been rebooted a few times since. We never thought of the connection but we only saw the fragmentation problem appearing after moving to our new server. The other server hadn't been rebooted for over a year

Comment: If the fragmentation is so heavy that you need to do it every *day*, though, that would mean the server reboots several times a day. If that's your problem, you'd expected to have seen more operational issues than a fragmented index...

Comment: No, the server definitely doesn't reboot multiple times a day. But even though it has been running for the last 18 days non-stop, it is still possible that the new guids that are being generated are lower than the highest value in the table - meaning the row would get written somewhere in between existing rows, right?

Comment: Use identity would fix this